# Linear Algebra Solve for Matrix $X$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-equations

$$
X - 
\begin{pmatrix} 2 & 1 & 1 \\ 0 & 3 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 & 4 \end{pmatrix} 
X =
\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 & 1 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 1 & 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}
$$

So I got this equation where I need to solve for $X$.
I thought to put the equation in the form of $AX  = B$,
which in my case would be something like $-AX+X=B$ (Correct me if I'm wrong).
I did try to find the inverse of $A$ to have it inverse in both side then turn $AX$ in the LHS to it identity matrix but I don't think thats the right way to do it. Any thought about how to tackle this?

Comment: Write $X - AX = (I - A)X$. Can you proceed from here?

Comment: I'm not sure why you replace B with  (I-A)X

Comment: Hi Max. How would you go about solving $x-3x=4$? What is different now that you are working with matrices? What is the same?

Comment: I would factor x then divide by (1-3) at the end it will  x =  -2

Comment: Oh I think I get it now

Comment: if I apply the same concept I would get X=(I-A)−1 B (-1 inverse I don't know how to do subscript)

Answer (score 3):

Your equation is of the form 
$(1\!\!1-A)X=B$ then the solution will be $X=(1\!\!1-A)^{-1}B$.

Answer (score 1):

After double  checking I realize the answer was wrong and this is what I should if I did my computation right[image: Answer]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hello Max. Include your work as a part of your question itself. That would be more helpful, as you are asking for verification of your answer.